# How to receive files by bluetooth via command line headless?

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth

I have installed several bluetooth packages:

```
sudo apt-get install bluetooth bluez bluez-tools rfkill
```

and then tried to serve BT:

```
$sudo bt-obex -s /NAS/media/ScanInbox
bt-obex: obex service is not found
Did you forget to run obexd?
```

The I called install

```
sudo apt install obexd-server
```

and it installed numerous Unity and Gnome packages, although my machine is headless and I probably dont need it.

After that I still can't

```
$ sudo service obex start
obex: unrecognized service
$ sudo service obexd start
obexd: unrecognized service
$ sudo service obexd-server start
obexd-server: unrecognized service
$ sudo service obexd-service start
obexd-service: unrecognized service
$ sudo bt-obex -s /NAS/media/ScanInbox
bt-obex: obex service is not found
Did you forget to run obexd?
```

How to accomplish? There is no any service with name like obex. What does installer of `obex-server` did?